# Access-Control-Allow-Origin blocks POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

Trying to fetch data from my server. It works for GET, since I added this to server code:

```
app.get('/getter*', async (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    
    let workoutNumber = req._parsedUrl.query
    var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('public/workout.json'));
    res.status(200).send(data.workouts[workoutNumber])
})
```

However it does not work for my POST request. Here is the server code:

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    
    var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('public/workout.json'));
    data.workouts.push(req.body);
    fs.writeFileSync('public/workout.json',JSON.stringify(data))
    
    res.status(200).send(data)
})
```

And this is how I am trying to get POST working from my webpage script:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2})
});
```

Comment: The error message in your console should reveal what other headers you are missing

Comment: Access to fetch at 'MYURL' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
create.html:12 POST MYURL net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ create.html:12
create.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Sadly, I am unable to find out what you are referring to @Evert

Comment: You are probably missing support for the `OPTIONS` request then!

Comment: @Evert could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Best thing you can do is read the documentation, top to bottom. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS keep an eye out for the preflight request.